# Using view modifer in solidity gives error in truffle compiler "ParserError: Expected token LBrace got 'View'"

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, remix

I am running `truffle test` with the following simple test contract, however it seems that it doesn't understand the `view` modifier.

#### Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract MetaCoin {
    function getBlockNumber()
    public
    view
    returns (uint)
    {
        return block.number;
    }
}
```

#### The output looks like:

```
$ truffle test
Compiling ./contracts/MetaCoin.sol...
Compiling ./test/TestMetacoin.sol...
Compiling truffle/Assert.sol...
Compiling truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol...

/contracts/MetaCoin.sol:7:5: ParserError: Expected token LBrace got 'View'
    view
    ^
```

The view works in Remix, what is missing in my truffle environment that is throwing this error?

The Remix compilation version is (0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.Emscripten.clang)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `$ truffle version`

Unless I miss my guess, it's not compiling with `0.4.18` so it's confused.

Truffle comes with its own JS compiler that lags behind `solc`, so it usually works best to lock that version in Remix so you have consistency through the whole process. For example, Truffle 3.4.11 gave us solidity 0.4.15. It that's the case, then it makes sense to select 0.4.15 in Remix.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Rob. `truffle version` returns `Truffle v3.4.11 (core: 3.4.11)
Solidity v0.4.15 (solc-js)` changing the setting to `0.4.15` in Remix gives the same error as truffle. So i think your assessment that truffle lags `solc` is correct.

Comment: In case it isn't clear or helps someone else, `view` is new. In `0.4.15` you'll be fine with `constant`. Thanks for the "accept".